# Accessing Telegram API via web-based client

Tags: api, telegram

I am studying Telegram API to develop a web-based app to communicate with Telegram API server but stumble upon this statement.

**The protocol is designed for access to a server API from applications running on mobile devices. It must be emphasized that a web browser is not such an application.**

Does this anyway tell us that Telegram API is ONLY accessible by Mobile-based applications (Clients) such as those on Android, iOS and etc?

Comment: https://github.com/zhukov/webogram

Comment: Thanks   Konstantin V. Salikhov!!!